# Linq request group by

Tags: linq

I'd like to group my request by FkOperateur and FkPstStd but I still need information in the select new part. How should I proceed to get IdPoste, FkStandard, IsValidated, Date depending on the group part result

```
var shortFormations =
  (from f in _context.Formations
   where f.FkPstStdNavigation.FkPosteNavigation.FkZoneNavigation.FkBatimentNavigation.IdBatiment == Batiment && (f.FkOperateurNavigation.Equipe == Equipe || Equipe == null)
   group f by new { f.FkOperateur, f.FkPstStd } into formation
   select new shortFormations
   {
       FkOperateur = formation.Key.FkOperateur,
       FkPstStd = formation.Key.FkPstStd,
       IdPoste = f.FkPstStdNavigation.FkPosteNavigation.IdPoste,
       FkStandard = f.FkPstStdNavigation.FkStandard,
       IsValidated = f.IsValidated,
       Date = f.DateFormation,
   })
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ToList();
```

I can't get IdPoste FkStandard IsValidated and Date
return f doesn't exist on current context on these line.

Could you explain me please.

```
Select
    fk_operateur,Fk_Pst_Std, max(date_formation)
FROM
    Formations
GROUP by
    Fk_Operateur,Fk_Pst_Std
```

that's a try in SQL but I'm not able to get others column mentionned before

returns

| fk_operateur | FkPstStd | date_formation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Adate |

and many other rows

Answer (score 1):

Since its grouped, to access the mentioned fields, you will have to look in the *Values* and select the correct item. As in, something like

```
select new shortFormations
   {
       FkOperateur = formation.Key.FkOperateur,
       FkPstStd = formation.Key.FkPstStd,
       IdPoste = formation.FirstOrDefault()
                    .FkPstStdNavigation.FkPosteNavigation.IdPoste,
       ....
```

or order it and then select the correct record

Comment: the thing is these informations are in f and not in formation (from f in _context.Formations)
So I should do f.Values.....  but the thing is "the name f does not exist in current context" 
Else if I use formation like you mentionned I got message error on values Compiler Error CS1061

Comment: @DimitriB Please try formation.FirstOrDefault().FkPstStdNavigation.FkPosteNavigation.IdPoste. Skip the .Values. Part

Comment: Perfect it's working i'll try to get max on date formation to check if it's work. thank you very much. I don't understand tho why it work like this could you explain me please?

Comment: @DimitriB All information of the entities are in the formation variable as you have used 'into formation'. Now we can access the Keys directly as 'formation.Key' and all the remaining values are collection of objects within the given key. So, for a FkOperateur and FkPstStd, we might have multiple records with this key varying on other parameters. So, we need to filter out which record in this collection is that we required against this key combination, maybe the one with the highest value or the most recent one. Not sure if I am conveying the idea.